# g++ option to show what classes are created from templates

Tags: c++, g++

Is there some g++ option which shows what classes are created from templates? For example there is template definition in original source code:

```
template <class T>
struct SomeStruct { T variable; };

SomeStruct<int> instance;
```

and I would like to see implementation of SomeStruct< int>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that info with the `-fdump-class-hierarchy` flag.  It'll list a lot more than you're asking for, but if search for lines that start with `Class`, you'll find what you're looking for.

**EDIT**:  Here's some output from a program that includes `iostream`.  You can see there are instantiations of `char` and `wchar_t`:

```
Class std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >
Class std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sentry
Class std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >
Class std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::sentry
Class std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >
Class std::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >
Class std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sentry
Class std::basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >
Class std::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::sentry
Class std::basic_iostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >
```

Answer (score -1):

The implementation is just as obvious as it seems: You put the real type in for `T`.

```
struct SomeStruct<int> { int variable; };
```

Comment: And if the template is specialized for int?